# How do interpret the notation $\operatorname{Max}(\mathopen|x\mathclose|,\mathopen|y\mathclose|)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I just started calc 3 and there are problems with the notation $\operatorname{Max}(a,b)$. I haven't seen it in other courses, for example, calc 2, yet there is nothing in my book about it so I suspect it's supposed to be prerequisite knowledge.

An example question is, sketch the following set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$: $\{(x,y); \operatorname{Max}(\mathopen|x\mathclose|,\mathopen|y\mathclose|) \leq1\}$.

What do I do/how should I think?

Comment: are you sure it's $Max(|x|,|y)$ and not $Max(|x|,|y|)$?

Comment: $\max(a,b)$ just means the max of $a,b$.  formally $\max(a,b) = a$ if $a \ge b$ and $\max (a,b) = b$ if $a < b$.  (if $a = b$ then $\max(a,b)=a\implies \max(a,b) = b$.).  so $\{(x,y); \max(|x|,|y|) \le 1$ would be all the $(x,y)$ where the larger of the two absolute values is less than or equal to $1$.  If the larger is less than or equal to one then both ab values are.  So both $x,y$ are between $-1, 1$.  so the graph with be all points where $-1\le x\le 1;-1\le y\le 1$ or, in other words a solid rectangle.

Comment: @SagarM yes it was a typo!

Comment: @fleablood alright I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\max (A,B) = $ the larger value of $A$ or $B = \begin{cases}A&&if\ A> B\\B&&if\ B > A\\A&which\ is\ = B&if\ A=B\end{cases}$

So $\{(x,y)|\max(|x|,|y|) \le 1\}=$

$\{(x,y): |y| \le |x|$ and $|x| \le 1$ or $|x| \le |y|$ and $|y|\le 1\}=$

$\{(x,y): |y|\le |x|\le 1$ or $|x|\le |y|\le 1\}=$

$\{(x,y): 0\le |y|\le |x|\le 1$ or $0\le |x|\le |y|\le 1\}=$

$\{(x,y): 0\le |y|\le 1$ and $0\le |x|\le 1\} =$

$\{(x,y): -1\le y \le 1$ and $-1\le x \le 1\}=$

the solid rectange from the corner $(-1,-1)$ to the corner $(1,1)$.

Comment: I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 3):

$\operatorname{Max}(a,b)$ is just the number that is the maximum of $a$ and $b$.  So, for example, $$\operatorname{Max}(41,12) = 41.$$  As for $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: \operatorname{Max}(\mathopen|x\mathclose|,\mathopen|y\mathclose|) \leq1\},$$ we can think of this as the region of the $(x,y)$ plane made of the regions where either $|y|\le |x|\le 1$ or $|x|\le |y|\le 1$.  See [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nrxjv7etsl).

Comment: Oh okey that makes sense, so for exmaple if the $\leq1$ criteria wasn't there, the area would simply be unbounded?

Comment: Just having $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}: \operatorname{Max}(\mathopen|x\mathclose|,\mathopen|y\mathclose|)\},$ wouldn't make sense, you need a condition on $\operatorname{Max}(|a|,|b|)$ for the notation to be meaningful in defining a set.